# JQuery hide div based on url hash and string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to hide a div based on the url hash tag. I'm using a jquery plugin called zozo tabs that allows for deep-linking and it shows and hides divs.

There is a particular div on the page (not in the tab area) I would like to hide given the url/s. I've searched but cannot figure it out. Please excuse my javascript noobness!!! I've tried this. No such luck. It doesnt seem to work. Any help would greatly appreciated.

I've tried php but it doesnt work on the hash

To start the plugin creates this type of url

```
http://localhost:8888/site/funds/#tabbed-nav=fund-strategy
```

The html is:

```html
 <ul>
    <li data-link="fund-strategy"><a>Fund Strategy</a></li>
    <li data-link="portfolio-characteristics"><a>Portfolio Characteristics</a></li>
    <li data-link="performance"><a>Performance</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="strategy">This copy shows when the li is clicked on</div>
```

This is me attempting to hide a div given the url with js

```js
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQ(document).ready(function() { 
    var url = document.location.href;

    if (url.indexOf('http://localhost:8888/site/funds/#tabbed-nav=fund-strategy') >= 0) {
        jQ('.fourth').hide();
    };
});


<div class="fourth">Hide me please!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use something like this:

```
var currentHash = window.location.hash;
if (currentHash=="#tabbed-nav=fund-strategy") {
   $('.fourth').hide();
}
```

Be sure that there is a html element with class 'fourth' in your html code. Otherwise this will not hide anything.

Comment: Technically both answers should work however they dont. Could it be because of the data-link and not the use of id/# on the document itself.

Comment: window.location.hash includes the leading "#". Thus the correct comparison is ...currentHash == "#tabbed-nav=fund-strategy"...

Answer (score 0):

I think i pinpointed the problem. The zozo tabs utilizes hashchange. So after hitting my head against the wall and HUGE inspiration from users here. I downloaded the ba.hashchange and wrapped the given answers in a hashchange function here is the code if anyone is interested. This seemed to work.

```
var jz = jQuery.noConflict();
jz(function(){
  jz(window).hashchange( function(){
  // Alerts every time the hash changes!
    var hash = document.location.hash;

    if (hash == '#tabbed-nav=risk' || hash == '#tabbed-nav=fund-strategy') {
        jz('.fourths').show();  
    } else {
        jz('.fourths').hide();  
    }

})
   jz(window).hashchange();

 });
```